# Processing: Keyboard stuck typing only boxes

Tags: processing

I have a troubling issue here:

Screenshot showing boxes in Processing editor

[image]

As you can see, whatever I'm typing, it will display little boxes. I don't have this kind of problem with other software, only with [Processing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processing_(programming_language)).

How can I fix this?

Comment: What language are you using? Have you tried uninstalling and reinstalling?

Comment: Oh sorry! French language.

Comment: Check settings and change font.

Comment: Yeah, I was just about to write the solution for everyone !
By the way, thank you for editing my post !